# Cannot iterate a queryset in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this model

```
class AgeRange(models.Model):
    frm = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    to = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
```

Now, when I try to fill a dropdown list by values contracted from frm+to fileds.
So, I run this queryset:

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ranges = AgeRange.objects.all().values()
    print(ranges)
    for item in ranges:
        print(item.frm)
```

It prints ranges as following:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 2, 'frm': '1', 'to': '18'} ..... so on.
```

Then, I get this error :

```
print(item.frm)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'frm'
```

I'm confused why it could not recogniez "frm" when I try to iterate the queryset :

```
for item in ranges:
    print(item.frm)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should remove `values` if you want all attributes in queryset.
Because `values()` return a dictionary of field values which is passed as arguments

```
ranges = AgeRange.objects.all()
print(ranges)
for item in ranges:
    print ( item.frm)
```

try this way you can get frm

Answer (score 1):

It's because you converted your queryset to a list of dictionaries.

Either do:

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ranges = AgeRange.objects.all().values()
    print(ranges)
    for item in ranges:
        print(item['frm'])
```

or

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ranges = AgeRange.objects.all()
    print(ranges)
    for item in ranges:
        print(item.frm)
```